# Injected resource type ManagedScheduledExecutorService is invalid

Tags: intellij-idea, ejb

I'm injecting a javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedScheduledExecutorService via javax.annotation.Resource-Annotation. IntelliJ (2019-3-2 Ultimate Edition) displays the error message "Injected resource type ManagedScheduledExecutorService is invalid". The compilation runs without errors and the program works. The error message can be suppressed with the @SuppressWarnings("EjbEnvironmentInspection"). Is this ok?